# Export command not found in su - user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, su

Starting with root, I want execute a sql script with another `$USER`. But I have to set the right `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$PATH` for `$USER`.

With this command I receive error ***`export: command not found`***

```
su - $USER -c "export ORACLE_HOME=$ORA_HOME;export PATH=$ORA_HOME/bin:$PATH;sqlplus / as sysdba"
```

My question is: starting executing a script in root, how can I export a environment variable for another user and execute a command using that environment variable?

Comment: Perhaps the default shell of `$USER` is one that does not have an `export` (`csh` or `tcsh` for example)

Comment: ksh and I don't have problem using export outside su - user

Comment: @NxA yes, but that's your shell, right? What does `su - $USER -c 'echo $SHELL'` print?

Comment: yes you are right, is set to CSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As steeldriver commented, it's likely that your target user is using csh or tcsh.
If you want to be sure of the shell that you're using, invoke it explicitly:

```sh
su - "$USER" -c \
  "/bin/ksh -c 'export ORACLE_HOME=$ORA_HOME;export PATH=$ORA_HOME/bin:$PATH;sqlplus / as sysdba'"
```

While the (sub)shell will contain any (exported) environment variables from the main shell, it will not contain any (unexported) shell variables from the user's main shell.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to export anyway. Just run:

```
su - $USER -c "ORACLE_HOME=$ORA_HOME;PATH=$ORA_HOME/bin:$PATH;sqlplus / as sysdba"
```

The `export` is only needed if you need the variables to be inherited by any child shells launched by your shell. Here, you're launching the command from the same shell, so there's no need to `export`.

But, as pointed out in the comments, that won't help if `sqlplus` needs to see those variables, only if they need to be set in order to find sqlplus correctly. If that fails, try:

```
su - $USER -c "ORACLE_HOME='$ORA_HOME' PATH='$ORA_HOME/bin:$PATH' sqlplus / as sysdba"
```

Comment: It's likely that `sqlplus` needs to see the variables (at least `ORACLE_HOME`).

Comment: @Kusalananda that was my original thought as well, but I couldn't get that to work. However, that was just because I was using `su -c 'foo=bar echo "a:$foo"'` to test, stupidly forgetting that the string would be expanded before the actual command so of course it didn't work! D'oh!